# Uart1 & Uart3 not working at same time in pic18fk67k40

Tags: pic18, mikroc

I am using PIC18f67k40 with internal clock at 8Mhz (IDE 7.5).
I did led blinking and simple UART1 transmit that works fine.

Next while trying UART1 & UART3 at same time, only UART1 works... (UART1 init first then UART3 init)
if i changes init order UART3 works but UART1 not works,

Pins for UART1 : (Tx=RC6 & Rx=RC7) and
UART3 : (Tx=RE0 & Rx=RE1)
I'm using default pins only, is there Peripheral pin mapping necessary or what should i do ?

[Sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i37mP.png)

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Please include the code not as image. Whats inside yout init functions?

Comment: that's all mikroc predefined functions, anyway problem solved, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, we have to use UART_Set_Active() function before using them when we deal with two or more UART'S.